# Unique value check via flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, unique-field

I've built a record triggered flow that when a Contact record is created, calls an Apex method that generates a random 10 digit number and puts that value on the newly created record. However, I need to ensure this value is unique and does not exist on any existing Contact records. If it does, call the method again and again until the value is unique.

The field (that is being updated) already has the "unique" option selected so a duplicate value won't be able to save regardless but how would I make the flow re-call the method until it successfully creates a unique value? Do I need a loop? Do I need to query all Contact records in the flow? Do I use a fault path? Or am I missing something entirely?

[image]

Please let me know anything that can push me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the 15-character record ID?

Comment: the client wants to important the old records which are 10 digits long and only contain 0123456789ABCDEF, and wants to maintain that format for additional records once moved to salesforce

Comment: extend the apex class to generate the number and check for uniqueness; regenerating if a dup

Comment: @cropredy what sort of loop would make sense in this case? a do-while?

Comment: that would work - note there are limits to be taken into account -- # of SOQL calls per transaction.  A cleverer strategy would be to generate 10 unique Ids at once, then a single SOQL checking all 10 and take the first non-dup